# "Error installing MLKitBarcodeScanning"- Getting this error in flutter

Tags: flutter, barcode, google-mlkit

While i try to install a package https://pub.dev/packages/ai_barcode_scanner , it is working fine in android but not in iOS. Issue occurring when pod install. Please help me and it would be appreciated.

Error while pod install

[!] Error installing MLKitBarcodeScanning
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/c7/_n3dd9n574zcpm8m4tr585p80000gn/T/d20240209-5184-1y6kriy/file.tgz https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/cb95d1eb922d1c4f/MLKitBarcodeScanning-3.0.0.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.12.0 cocoapods-downloader/1.6.3'